# Wrapping pymc3 model in a function

Tags: python, function, modeling, pymc

Does anyone know of a method for storing a `pymc3` model within in a standard Python 3 function?

I am looking to store this function locally to be called multiple times within a `Jupyter` environment, with the functioning aiming to return visuals after the model is instantiated. The function takes in a control and experimental condition and transforms them into `numpy` arrays before performing the modeling and `MCMC`:

```py
    def bayesian_ab_test(x ,y):

       y1 = x
       y2 = y

       data = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.r_[y1, y2], group=np.r_[['y2']*len(y2), 
       ['y1']*len(y1)]))
    
       μ_m = data.value.mean()
       μ_s = data.value.std() * 2
    
       σ_low = sd_low
       σ_high = sd_high
    
       group1_std = pm.Uniform('group1_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
       group2_std = pm.Uniform('group2_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
    
       ν = pm.Exponential('ν_minus_one', 1/29.) + 1
    
       λ1 = group1_std**-2
       λ2 = group2_std**-2

       group1 = pm.StudentT('Control_1', nu=ν, mu=group1_mean, lam=λ1, observed=y1)
       group2 = pm.StudentT('NBA', nu=ν, mu=group2_mean, lam=λ2, observed=y2)
    
       diff_of_means = pm.Deterministic('difference of means', group2_mean - group1_mean)
       diff_of_stds = pm.Deterministic('difference of stds', group2_std - group1_std)
       effect_size = pm.Deterministic('effect size', diff_of_means / np.sqrt((group1_std**2 + 
       group2_std**2) / 2))
    
       trace = pm.sample(1000)

    return trace
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: No model on context stack, which is needed to instantiate distributions. Add variable inside a 'with model:' block, or use the '.dist' syntax for a standalone distribution.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
def bayesian_ab_test(x ,y):

   y1 = x
   y2 = y

   data = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.r_[y1, y2], group=np.r_[['y2']*len(y2), 
       ['y1']*len(y1)]))
    
   μ_m = data.value.mean()
   μ_s = data.value.std() * 2
    
   σ_low = sd_low
   σ_high = sd_high

   with pm.Model():
    
       group1_std = pm.Uniform('group1_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
       group2_std = pm.Uniform('group2_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
    
       ν = pm.Exponential('ν_minus_one', 1/29.) + 1
    
       λ1 = group1_std**-2
       λ2 = group2_std**-2

       group1 = pm.StudentT('Control_1', nu=ν, mu=group1_mean, lam=λ1, observed=y1)
       group2 = pm.StudentT('NBA', nu=ν, mu=group2_mean, lam=λ2, observed=y2)
    
       diff_of_means = pm.Deterministic('difference of means', group2_mean - group1_mean)
       diff_of_stds = pm.Deterministic('difference of stds', group2_std - group1_std)
       effect_size = pm.Deterministic('effect size', diff_of_means / np.sqrt((group1_std**2 + 
       group2_std**2) / 2))
    
       trace = pm.sample(1000)

    return trace
```

this will create a model every time the function is called and sample from it. Or, to have the function extend an already existing model, do:

```
def bayesian_ab_test(x ,y, model):

   with model:

       y1 = x
       y2 = y

       data = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=np.r_[y1, y2], group=np.r_[['y2']*len(y2), 
       ['y1']*len(y1)]))
    
       μ_m = data.value.mean()
       μ_s = data.value.std() * 2
    
       σ_low = sd_low
       σ_high = sd_high
    
       group1_std = pm.Uniform('group1_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
       group2_std = pm.Uniform('group2_std', lower=σ_low, upper=σ_high)
    
       ν = pm.Exponential('ν_minus_one', 1/29.) + 1
    
       λ1 = group1_std**-2
       λ2 = group2_std**-2

       group1 = pm.StudentT('Control_1', nu=ν, mu=group1_mean, lam=λ1, observed=y1)
       group2 = pm.StudentT('NBA', nu=ν, mu=group2_mean, lam=λ2, observed=y2)
    
       diff_of_means = pm.Deterministic('difference of means', group2_mean - group1_mean)
       diff_of_stds = pm.Deterministic('difference of stds', group2_std - group1_std)
       effect_size = pm.Deterministic('effect size', diff_of_means / np.sqrt((group1_std**2 + 
       group2_std**2) / 2))
    
       trace = pm.sample(1000)

    return trace
```